# The page keeps running when dymanically creating Leaflet Layers based on Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

Issue --> My page seems to be in an infite loop or something. It keeps loading but i don't get an error

Aim --> Based on an id from the JSON field, I create an array of types. I also create 2 seperate arrays (1 for layer and 1 for color).

I want to create 1 layer per type and give their markers a unique color.

Process: I declare my 3 arrays with the following:

```
var typeArray = [];
var colorArray = [];
var layerArray = [];'
```

After which I go through the JSON File's output on classificationid and populate the type array which works fine. I have logged the values to validate

```
for( var i=0; i < jData.length; i++){
        if(typeArray.includes(jData[i].classificationid)){
            console.log(jData[i].classificationid + " is in array");
        }
        else{
            typeArray.push(jData[i].classificationid);
        }
    }
```

After which I iterate through the type create a color and layer array. The color array and function works fine. I have valdiated it.

```
for(var i = 0; i<typeArray.length; i++){
        colorArray[i] = getRandomRgb();
        layerArray[i] = L.layerGroup();
    }
```

So based on this, I assume if I had 2 types of classificationid, I would have a layerArray with 2 layer groups. (An array of objects)

In the code below, I iterate through my entire JSON in which I nest an iteration through the typeArray. If the type array matches the classification, I add a div icon to the respective layer. 
**The console.log(jData[i].classificationid + "   matches    " + typeArray[j]); gives correct input to the console after which I see nothing else in the console**

```
for(var i=0; i < jData.length; i++){
        console.log("I = " + i);

        for(var j=0; i<typeArray.length; j++){
            if(jData[i].classificationid == typeArray[j]){
                console.log(jData[i].classificationid + "   matches    " + typeArray[j]);

                L.marker([jData[i].latitudey, jData[i].longitudex],{
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    html: '<i id ="icon1" class="fas fa-map-marker" style="font-size:48px;color:rgb(225, 80, 71)"></i>',
                    iconSize: [20, 20],
                    className: 'myDivIcon'
                })
            }).bindPopup(jData[i].addresscode).addTo(layerArray[j]);


            }
        }
```

Somewhere in this code is where I believe my issue lies.

Problem 1 - The markers don't get added to the layerArray
Problem 2 - I don't know how to change HTML rgb style based on the colorArray.

PLEASE HELPP :(

Comment: Please make sure to separate your problems / questions into different posts, with details specific to each of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think your loop is stuck here:

```
for(var j=0; i<typeArray.length; j++){
```

should be

```
for(var j=0; j<typeArray.length; j++){
```

Comment: Took me an embarrassingly long time to spot the difference between those lines :S

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Comment: @Saachi please _accept_ the answer if it solved one of your issues. As for the rest of your problem(s), open a new dedicated question instead of salvaging your post. Otherwise it becomes irrelevant with this answer and comments, making it useless to future readers.